# tailwind config dynamic object

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

How can I make a dynamic object?
I have a file tailwind.config.js and I want to import an object from a database

ex

```
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

function setColors() {
//Here I want to import it from a database
    return {
        danger: colors.rose,
        primary: colors.green,
        success: colors.green,
        warning: colors.yellow,
    };
}

module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: setColors(),
         }
      }
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If you are using Tailwind with PostCSS to purge out un-used CSS - which is most likely, then `tailwind.config.js` is the first thing that is read when the application boots up, and it's permanent, while database's data is not. But let's see

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to execute asynchronous code to fetch config values with Tailwind. A different option would be to have a separate script that queries the DB for the colors and writes that out to a JSON file. Then you can `require` the file in `tailwind.config.js` and apply it to your theme. The aforementioned script would need to be run before booting your build process (or whatever process runs Tailwind).